# using statement in asp.net web forms works locally but not live?

Tags: iis-7, webforms, asp.net-3.5

**UPDATE :** is there any iis 7 setting which might cause this issue? I recently moved to iis 7.0.

So I am having this weird issue where my code works locally but not when i deploy it live.
For example -

```
Employee e= new Employee();//does work locally 
Employee e= new Employee(); // does not work live..says cannot convert Employee to  MyLibrary.Model.Employee
MyLibrary.Model.Employee e= new MyLibrary.Model.Employee();////works live
```

So for some reason from the above code you can see it is not basically finding my using statements in the file.Although I have them it asks me to declares its full qualified name. Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

The only time I have seen problems like this when dealing with ASP.net is when a stale assembly has been cached.

Comment: I normally try two things 1) reset IIS 2) delete all the files and re-deploy

Comment: Also, are you by chance using any reflection/dynamic assembly loading?

Comment: is there any iis 7 setting which might cause this issue? I recently moved to iis 7.0

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have MyLibrary.Model.dll referenced in the live build.

Comment: it is being reference I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two different assemblies referenced that both define an "Employee" object?

If so, you will need to fully qualify the objects.